# Retrieve a rendered background image's dimensions with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I have a page with a list of items where each item has a square div containing a background image. This image can have dimensions which are either bigger, or smaller than the div itself. The background centered and contained in the div so it is always shown in the middle of the div. 
The css for this is as follows:

```
    .productImage
    {
      width:  225px; 
      height: 225px; 
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin-left:70px;
    }
```

The background-image itself is set using a jQuery call that modifies the css of the div.
This works like charm, however I would like to know the dimensions of the rendered background image. If the rendered is smaller than a specific dimension I would like to set a background color for aesthetic reasons.

I am currently unable to retrieve the dimensions of the rendered images. I have used the following code in a loop to try and retrieve the dimensions of the images, but this returns the **original** dimensions of the images, before they have been scaled into the div.

```
images[i] = new Image();
images[i].src = $('#image'+i).css('background-image').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
images[i].pos = i;

images[i].onload = function() {
var position = this.pos;
width = this.width;
height = this.height;

console.log("For image "+position+" the height is "+height+" and width is "+ width);
}
```

**How would I be able to find out the dimensions of the rendered background image using jQuery or pure Javascript? Is this even possible?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can do this by checking the dimension of the containing element instead of the background image itself since you have the background size set to `contain`

Comment: @Huangism That's what I thought as well, however this returns the 225x225 dimensions set in the css instead of the actual dimensions of the background image.

Comment: How big is your bg image? If your div is a set width then your bg will be a set width as well. The bg size contain will set the image at a max width or height of 225 which ever comes first. You should be able to figure out the dimensions based on that

Comment: Hmm so what you're basically saying is it might be an option to compare the bg image sizes to the dimensions of the div, and calculate the scaled dimensions based on that? Sounds plausible, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Something like that, you need to know the actual image size and since you know the size of the div and actual image size, you should know when it is used as bg and having bg size contain, will set the bg width or height at 225.

Answer (score 1):

After playing with Huangism's idea a bit I came to the following solution:

```
                images[i] = new Image();
                images[i].src = $('#image'+i).css('background-image').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
                images[i].pos = i;

                images[i].onload = function() {
                    var position = this.pos;
                    width = this.width;
                    height = this.height;
                    var divwidth = $('#image'+position).width();
                    var divheight = $('#image'+position).height();
                    var ratioH = divheight / height;
                    var ratioW = divwidth / width;
                    var scaleW = width * ratioH;
                    var scaleH = height * ratioW;

                    console.log("For image "+position+" the height is "+height+" and width "+ width +" and ratioH "+ratioH + " and ratioW " + ratioW  +" (Scaled width: "+scaleW+")" );

                    if(scaleW < 120 || scaleH < 100){
                    $('#image'+position).css('background-color', 'red');
                    }
                }
```

This code compares the image used as a background image's height and width with the dimensions of the div he is contained in. Based on this I calculate the scaling ratio between the original height and width and the maximum height and width within the div. 
This ratio is then multiplied with the opposing dimension (height * width ration, width * height ratio) to calculate the dimensions of the rendered image.

Comparing the values in the console to measurements in Photoshops shows they are a perfect match!

I hope this answer can help other users that want to know the dimensions of a rendered background image.

Answer (score 0):

Give the image an id then:

```
var width = document.getElementById('myImageID').offsetWidth;
var height= document.getElementById('myImageID').offsetHeight;
```

Comment: This would be a good solution if the image was actually an image element. However I'm using a div with a background-image element. I tried this approach and it gave me the dimensions of the div instead of the image.

Comment: Ah ok, well why not set a background-color anyway? it either shows if the image is smaller or it doesn't (the image will cover it) - desired result either way

Comment: There is a logo covering the div behind the actual div used for the product image. If for whatever reason the product image fails to load, the div behind it is shown showing the logo. If I use a default background color this is always covering the logo.